# Create object inside object in jolt

Tags: json, jolt

I want to create object inside object using jolt
My input is like

```json
{
  "rating-primary": 1,    
   //much more other stuff
}
```

and expected output should be

```json
{
  "rating": {
    "id": 1 // it should be the rating-primary
  }
  //remaining o/p
}
```

and there are much more in my spec for other stuff like below

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "i*|p*": {
        "@1,name": [
          "id",
          "publicIdentifier"
        ],
        "@1,nf-role": "\\@type",
        "@1,serial-number": "serial-number",
        "@1,orchestration-status": "lifeCyleState",
        "@1,sw-version": "versionNumber",
        "$": "resourceCharacteristics[#2].name",
        "@": "resourceCharacteristics[#2].value"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "resourceCharacteristics": "MANY",
      "*": "ONE"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "data": "data",
      "dummydata": [
        {
          "role": "customer"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "href": "=concat('resource/', @(1,id))",
      "note": {
        "text": "=concat(@(2,id), ' is hosted on')"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Just wanted to modify my spec to meet requirement. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: but the input quite unclear, and there's no expected output.

Answer (score 0):

As I could understand from the question,
you would add this line to the **shift** spec

```json
"*-primary": "&(0,1).id" // the replacement of the 1st asterisk from the current(0) level
```

which will convert it to

```json
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*-primary": "&(0,1).id",
      "i*|p*": {
        "@1,name": ["id", "publicIdentifier"],
        "@1,nf-role": "\\@type",
        "@1,serial-number": "serial-number",
        "@1,orchestration-status": "lifeCyleState",
        "@1,sw-version": "versionNumber",
        "$": "resourceCharacteristics[#2].name",
        "@": "resourceCharacteristics[#2].value"
      }
    }
  }
```